# Append backgrounding operator (&) to a command via a variable

Tags: bash

This works:

```
${START} &
```

This doesn't work:

```
APPLICATION_OUTPUT=`echo &`
${START} ${APPLICATION_OUTPUT}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
APPLICATION_OUTPUT="&"
${START} ${APPLICATION_OUTPUT}
```

Still not:

```
APPLICATION_OUTPUT=&
${START} ${APPLICATION_OUTPUT}
```

How can I append an "&" to a command with an arg?

You can let `START="FOO"`, or something better.

Comment: Have you tried using the backslash - ie \&? Bash may override the ampersand as a special character and you might need to un-override it.  Just a thought. Also don't forget that sometimes you may need to use the double-backslash in order to get the single backslash in a quoted string. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: Probably better off testing with something like: `echo $START &`

Comment: @MarkManning: `&` is _meant_ to be treated as a special char. here, namely as the Bash control operator that runs the command in the _background_. The OP's question is about how to store this operator in a _variable_.

Comment: As an aside: It is better not to use all-uppercase shell-variable names such as `$START`, so as to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

Comment: @mklement0 : Yes, that is true. That is why I said to try the backslash as usually a backslash in front of a character usually mean that character literally. Thus, if & does the background command (which I do know about) then \& might turn it just in to an ampersand and quoted ampersands would require the double-backslash. I don't use BASH  - I use CSH. So it was just a thought. And yes - I have used BASH in the past.  I just don't use it now. :-)

Comment: @MarkManning: What you're explaining here does not apply to the question and is therefore a distraction, which is what my previous comment tried to point out. (If anything, the question is about the _opposite_: how can I make a special char. that is being treated as a literal (due to being stored in a variable) special again?)

Comment: @mklement0 : Ah. Ok. I took his request literally which was "How can I append an "&" to a command". Which was the question I was trying to answer.

Comment: @mklement0 : Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options, roughly 'the safe' and 'the unsafe' (and a third, 'the function').

#### Safe

```
if [ "$run_in_background" = "yes" ]
then ${START} &
else ${START}
fi
```

This simply chooses which mode to use.  I'm assuming that the absence of double quotes around `${START}` is OK — you might be better off with an array hold the command and its arguments and then using double quotes: `"${START_ARRAY[@]}"` optionally with an `&` after it.

#### Unsafe

```
if [ "$run_in_background" = "yes" ]
then tail="&"
else tail=""
fi
eval ${START} $tail
```

This is a fraught operation.  If the user controls the content of `$START`, you have problems ensuring they haven't submitted code that will do damage.  It also re-reads the string that is produced by concatenating `${START}` and `$tail` and then rescans it.  If there were spaces or quotes or other special characters to be handled, you have to work hard to make `${START}` safe for the `eval`.  On the whole, this is not the way to go.

#### Function

```
start()
{
    ${START}
}

if [ "$run_in_background" = "yes" ]
then start &
else start
fi
```

The advantage of 'the function' over 'the safe' is that you don't have to repeat a long and possibly contorted command line — you just have to write the function once to execute whatever is needed, and then invoke the function to run in the background or not.

#### Which to use?

Either 'the safe' or 'the function'.  Both will work; both are reasonable.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really happy with your answer.

Comment: Good answer, but note that a potential _security problem_ arising from the user controlling the value of  `$START `is fundamental to _all_ your approaches - not just to the `eval` variant : a command stored in a variable is blindly executed - as such, _all_ variants presented here are unsafe;
What does apply specifically to the `eval` variant, however - as you state - is that the command may get interpreted _differently_.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` that terminates a command and causes it to run in the background, as basic shell syntax, must appear in the command *before* any parameter expansions occur. It is possible to determine that *some* command is to run without knowing exactly *which* command that will be, which is why you can store the name of the command to run in a parameter.

To do what you want requires a call to `eval` to evaluate a string resulting from the various expansions as a shell command.

```
$ START=xterm
$ APPLICATION_OUTPUT="&"
$ eval ${START} ${APPLICATION_OUTPUT}
# Runs 'xterm' in the background, because eval
# combines "xterm" and "&" into a single string
# "xterm &", which it then executes in the current
# shell.
```

Comment: Your explanation of why `&` can't be used via a variable (parameter) is helpful (although possibly too technical for the novice),
but it's worth mentioning that `eval` (while adding no _additional_ security risk here) potentially alters the outcome of the command
stored in `$START` (leaving aside the fact that all-uppercase variables should be avoided, and that using a scalar string variable is not a robust way to store a command): `START='echo $HOME'; $START; eval $START`

Comment: Right; I didn't want to get *too* into how `eval` works (or how to use it safely, if possible) because I don't recommend using it at all. The only thing to take away from this answer is that parameter expansions also produce *data*, not shell syntax, and that the `eval` command is the way to parse arbitrary data before executing it as code.